# How to change color of DataGrid Cell when empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid, I want to change the color of the cells when they are empty.
This works, however I want to place the style outside the Datagrid.
However I don't know how to achieve this.

So far I have:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid Name="Table1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" />                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't work. What is the correct way to set this style?

Comment: Is it just that you didn't tell the datagrid to use the style? CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"?

Comment: Indeed You can set DataGrid.Style or delete the key from your style so Framework will assume it's default one.

Comment: @J.H. I tried that, and It doesn't work.

Comment: @MajkeloDev I like that it should take it as the default style but it is not working. I removed the Key and still doesn't get applied.

Comment: Wait a second gonna test it.